# Como saber se a solução foi modificada?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Gostaria de fazer um código, que ao ser executado, saberia se a solução foi alterada e qual projeto da mesma sofreu alteração, mas não sei se existe um método para tomar como base. Então gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Você está fazendo um add-in? Ou seria uma aplicação que roda paralelamente ao Visual Studio?

Comment: Uma aplicação que roda paralelamente ao VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe uma classe no .Net que é usada para monitorar alterações no sistema de arquivos:

- [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Com ela você pode fazer o seguinte código para ser notificado sempre que um arquivo mudar:

```
// Criar uma instância do FileSystemWatcher e configurá-la.
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(
    "C:\\MinhaSolucao\\", // caminho raiz da solução a ser monitorada
    "*.csproj"            // vamos monitorar os arquivos `csproj` dentro do caminho acima
    );

// Adicionando os eventos para notificação de alterações.
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatcherEvent);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatcherEvent);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatcherEvent);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(WatcherEvent);

// Iniciar o monitoramento.
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Código que recebe as notificações:

```
static void WatcherEvent(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // alterações nos arquivos ocorreram!
    // verificar o argumento `e` para saber o que ocorreu.
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, caiu como uma luva.

Comment: Beleza... se precisar de ajuda com a classe, me fala que adiciono mais informações sobre como usar.